# is there any way to change .exe file into .apk?

Tags: apk, exe

i made a python script with tkinter, python and i turned it into a program folder with .exe file that woks correctly using auto py to exe .
I m asking if there is a similar solution to turn this exe folder into an apk file and thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand the substance of your question.
I am not too much in the style of putting -1 on questions because I believe that no question is good or bad.

Be aware that there is no miracle method to transform your script into an android application. There are solutions to do things with python and android (notably Kivy) but not with Tkinter ...

Happy development!
See you soon

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are ways of changing exe files to apk, but some controls (touch, scoll) doesn't always work as you might expect it to.
You can find how to do this [here](https://techonation.com/convert-exe-to-apk/) although I wouldn't exactly recommend it

Comment: Oh and if you are asking to pakage the python file into apk rather than exe to apk, then this is a question asked and answered hundreds of times on stack overflow so look at those answers